# Excel VBA, error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

Tags: excel, vba

I get the error '-2147417848 (80010108)' when running this code, I've marked the code where the error uccures as bold. Sometimes I also get an error at the last bold part of the code but no error code. I have tried with diffrent methods of copying, copy from the same sheet, used "Application.CutCopyMode = False" etc. but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Pages As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Del1 As Integer
    Dim Del2 As Integer
    Dim Offset As Integer
    Dim Offset1 As Integer
    
    Pages = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count
 
    For I = 1 To Pages
        If IsEmpty(Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0)) = True And Not Intersect(Range("A42:J77").Offset(Offset, 0), Selection) Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Source").Range("B14").Copy Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0)
        End If
        
        If IsEmpty(Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0)) = True And Not Intersect(Range("A42:J77").Offset(Offset, 0), Selection) Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Source").Range("B14").Copy Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0)
        End If
        
        If IsEmpty(Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0)) = True And Not Intersect(Range("A42:J77").Offset(Offset, 0), Selection) Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Source").Range("B14").Copy Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0)
        End If
        
        If Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0) = "Delete" Then
            Del1 = (Offset + 43)
            Del2 = (Offset + 43 + 11)
            Rows(Del1 & ":" & Del2).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0) = "Insert" Then
            Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0) = Sheets("Source").Range("A16").Offset(Offset1, 0)
            Del1 = (Offset + 43)
            Del2 = (Offset + 43 + 11)
            Rows(Del1 & ":" & Del2).EntireRow.Insert
        **ElseIf Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0) = "KL1408" Then
            Del1 = (Offset + 44)
            Sheets("Source").Range("A2:B9").Copy Range("A" & Del1)**
          End If
        
        If Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0) = "Delete" Then
            Del1 = (Offset + 55)
            Del2 = (Offset + 55 + 11)
            Rows(Del1 & ":" & Del2).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0) = "Insert" Then
            Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0) = Sheets("Source").Range("A17").Offset(Offset1, 0)
            Del1 = (Offset + 55)
            Del2 = (Offset + 55 + 11)
            Rows(Del1 & ":" & Del2).EntireRow.Insert
        **ElseIf Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0) = "KL1408" Then
            Del1 = (Offset + 56)
            Sheets("Source").Range("A2:B9").Copy Range("A" & Del1)**
        End If
        
        If Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0) = "Delete" Then
            Del1 = (Offset + 67)
            Del2 = (Offset + 67 + 11)
            Rows(Del1 & ":" & Del2).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0) = "Insert" Then
            Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0) = Sheets("Source").Range("A18").Offset(Offset1, 0)
            Del1 = (Offset + 67)
            Del2 = (Offset + 67 + 11)
            Rows(Del1 & ":" & Del2).EntireRow.Insert
        **ElseIf Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0) = "KL1408" Then
            Del1 = (Offset + 68)
            Sheets("Source").Range("A2:B9").Copy Range("A" & Del1)**
        End If
        
        
        **Sheets("Source").Range("A16").Offset(Offset1, 0) = Range("A43").Offset(Offset, 0)
        Sheets("Source").Range("A17").Offset(Offset1, 0) = Range("A55").Offset(Offset, 0)
        Sheets("Source").Range("A18").Offset(Offset1, 0) = Range("A67").Offset(Offset, 0)**
        
        
        Offset = Offset + 36
        Offset1 = Offset1 + 3
        
    Next I

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're changing a sheet from within a Change event, so you're getting recursion. You should disable events before you make changes to the same sheet.

Comment: @Rory Thank you! Is that something you should always do?

Comment: It depends on the situation.

Comment: Within a `Change` event you'd typically work with the supplied `Target` range, and not `Selection` - they're not always the same thing.  If `Sheets("Source")` is the worksheet where this code is running then you can use `Me` in place of that.